mosquitto using in IOT
I am designing a communication system using MOSQUITTO
The platform consistently collects data from sensors(temperature, pressure) and fabricates some specific comprehensive data(temperature warning, abnormal pressure...).
We use an array to temporarily store these data and send them through mosquitto at a regular time, and I want to make sure,
1 All data can be sent at least 1 and only 1 times(USING QOS2?)
2 Know the exact time when the net go wrong, so I can immediately store the data in DataBase(sqlite3). Indeed, I have tried heartbeat(need at least 5s to know the error), but I might miss the data for this period
3 make sure all data can be sent as soon as possible, the send speed and receive speed should be similar, but I actually find about gradually extending the time gap
In a word, I want to know how you guys prepare for the net error when data should be precisely sent to the server. Thank you
I have tried QOS2 to send data
Net go wrong --> store data to database(8-10s after the callback of heartbeat system !!!I will miss these data in this period)
Meet a gap between the send speed and receive speed

I don't know anything about mosquitto... can client keep track of the last record accepted by server?  Failing that can you ask the server what the last record it has for client?  Then send anything newer.

A traditional way to handle this is using some kind of sliding window. You queue your messages as frames, and track which frame was last acknowledged by the server. If frames are not acknowledged after some time interval, you retry after the last-acknowledged frame. Receiver must periodically acknowledge frames and hande duplicate frames. Like the previous commenter, I've never encountered MOSQUITTO. Maybe it provides something like this, or something more modern. You can expand your audience by providing a summary of what this system offers that's relevant to your application, as an [edit].
